# How do I remvoe a Alfi widespread faucet? It seems to be cloged. It is all brass

Tags: bathroom, faucet

Alfi AB1326 widespread bathroom faucet.  The spout seems to be one piece and will not fit through the whole in the counter.  The T on the bottom looks like it should just unscrew,but it does not.  There is no information about this item from the manufacture.

Comment: How about a few pictures, top and bottom so we can see what you see.

Answer (score 1):

It is inserted from the top and then held with a nut from underneath.

Under the counter turn off the two hot and cold water valves

Then unscrew the two waterlines from the faucet.

Next unscrew the nut just under the counter holding the faucet and pull the faucet up.

[image: faucet]